# Creating a "domino effect" with Ajax in JSF2

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2

I'm trying to create a domino like effect when rendering different panelGroups using JSF2 and Ajax. The idé is that depending on the outcome a certain panel will be rendered and shown which in turn renders a third panel, is it possible to create a domino like effect with Ajax to render each panel in succession?

I'm sure I've read about this somewhere, I just can't to find the article again :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind the group components to the view scope and use [`UIComponent#isRendered()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#isRendered%28%29).

```
<h:panelGroup binding="#{group1}" rendered="#{bean.someCondition}">
    ...
</h:panelGroup>

<h:panelGroup binding="#{group2}" rendered="#{group1.rendered}">
    ...
</h:panelGroup>

<h:panelGroup binding="#{group3}" rendered="#{group2.rendered}">
    ...
</h:panelGroup>

...
```

Comment: You, my good sir, are truly a King among web designers...
I humbly thank you once again. :)

Comment: You're welcome. I am not a web designer (my son of 9 does it better). I am a web developer ;)